# Considerations for a Digital to Film workflow?

Tags: workflow, digital, darkroom

I've always loved the deep blacks of a wet mono print, it's not something I see often (if ever) from an inkjet and so I'd like to try to do a wet print from a digital negative.

I don't really want to shoot film though and I still want the ability to instantly review my shot so my plan is to shoot digital then do some basic tweaks in Photoshop, do a mono conversion, invert the colour in the image and send it off to a company that will send me a slide back which (being a negative) I can then print.

Are you SE folks aware of any other photographers who do this kind of process or if you've done it yourself, are there any pitfalls I should be prepared for?

Comment: Sounds like a good one for @Stan Rogers

Comment: @dpollitt -- Not really. We were mostly concerned with going the other direction in my day (film to digital prepress). And I only know a few weirdo dye transfer/carbon print enthusiasts who use film recorders anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Does it matter to you to do your own development?  It is probably easier just to have a good print house do the photographic print for you.  Any good professional print shop is going to be using a laser or LED photographic printer where they are using a photographic developer.  The only difference is that instead of using a negative, they use a laser or LED to expose the photo paper.

Comment: Unless you want to do the printing yourself, this is going to have the same equality. At some point the digital data has to be written onto something light sensitive- slide film or paper.

Comment: +1 -- In any case, the inversion step would be unnecessary, since any service that uses a film recorder to produce the negs will be using, well, negative film.

Comment: I think part of it is that I want to get in the darkroom as much as anything, so yes that part is important to me.  There is an issue of cost as well since I regularly print up to 40x50cm/20x16" which makes getting C-Types rather than giclee/inkjet prints prohibitively expensive.